# STM32F4xx barebones SPI (HAL initialisation)

Tags: stm32, spi

I am working on a piece of software for an STM32F4xx device which started from a STM32CubeMX generated project.

I am using the SPI peripheral which has been initialized using the HAL library.
This is an example of an SPI write function that works:

```
void spi_write(uint8_t data) {
    HAL_SPI_Transmit(&hspi2,&data,1,HAL_MAX_DELAY);
}
```

If I want to send data using the SPI without using the HAL library, but doing it barebones on the registers (because it is faster) it does not work. This is my implementation:

```
void spi_write(uint8_t data) {
    (&hspi2)->Instance->DR = data;
    while (!((&hspi2)->Instance->SR & ((uint16_t)0x0002))); //Check TXE flag (SPI_I2S_FLAG_TXE)
    while ((&hspi2)->Instance->SR & ((uint16_t)0x0080)); // Check busy flag (SPI_I2S_FLAG_BSY)
}
```

Any idea why the second implementation does not work? Thank you!

Comment: In what way does it not work?

Comment: It does not send any data.

Comment: The STM HAL Library's HAL_SPI_Transmit() does a __HAL_SPI_ENABLE(hspi) before writing to the DR. Are you sure the SPI peripheral you're writing to is actually *enabled* and not just *configured*?

Comment: It is probably not meaningfully faster unless the HAL is very poorly written.

Answer (score 1):

depending on the implementation of the SPI  probably you need to cast properly

`*(volatile uint8_t *)&SPIx -> DR = data;`

Then waiting for both flags after the send is pointless. Using the magic numbers is just ridiculous.

```
void spi_write(uint8_t data) 
{
    while (!(hspi2.Instance->SR & SPI_SR_TXE)));  // check  the CMSIS definition for you uC
    *(volatile uint8_t *)&hspi2.Instance->DR = data;
}
```

The last check is needed only if you are going to disable the SPI or you manually change the state of the CS pin and you have to wait until the last was transmitted.

Another errors - SR register is 32 bit not 16.
What is the point of using HAL for initialization if you want to use it the "bare regiser" way?